# Active Record schema problems

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am *attempting* to move from direct queries using the `sqlite3` gem over to Active Record.

Here are the Active Record settings:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'admins'
    create_table :admins do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :text,           :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'channels'
    create_table :channels do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :name,           :string
      table.column :users,          :integer
      table.column :topic,          :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'messages'
    create_table :messages do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :text,           :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'networks'
    create_table :networks do |table|
      table.column :name,           :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'servers'
    create_table :servers do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :ip,             :string
      table.column :port,           :integer
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'users'
    create_table :users do |table|
      table.column :network_id,     :integer
      table.column :global,         :integer
      table.column :global_max,     :integer
      table.column :local,          :string
      table.column :local_max,      :integer
    end
  end
end

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
end

class Messages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
end

class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
end
```

Since I have added the `belongs_to` to each class the database queries are not being saved to the database but no error messages are being shown which makes me believe that possibly I misunderstood how to use these `belongs_to` etc.

Basically all other tables have a `network_id` column that needs to be mapped to the `id` column of the `networks` table, so if someone tries to insert in to the `admins` table with a `network_id` of 1 but 1 is not present in the `networks` table it should fail.

Is `belongs_to` what I should be using here?

Also should I be using others such as `has_one`, `has_many` or? I am used to writing plain SQL queries so reading and trying to understand the Active Record documentation is a bit confusing!

Answer (score 0):

For your Network model:

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admins, inverse_of: :network
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :network
  has_many :channels, inverse_of: :network
  has_many :messages, inverse_of: :network
  has_many :servers, inverse_of: :network
end
```

1. You should also add the inverse relationships to each of your other models.
2. "Messages" should be singular.
3. You probably want to add a "dependent" option for the "has_many" relationships, such as "dependent: :destroy" so that if a Network is removed all its dependent records in the other tables are removed in a cascade.

With that out of the way, you simply need to add:

```
validates :network, presence: true
```

to your other models to require the network_id to map to an actual id in the networks table.  Additionally, you might take advantage of foreign keys (which sqlite3 might not support), and you probably also want to index the network_id columns in the other tables.

There's a lot of basic work to do here.

Comment: What does inverse mean?

Comment: Please reference http://api.rubyonrails.org/ and look up `has_many`.  To expand on this - you probably would do well to look at some of the RoR guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ and perhaps an RoR book.  The guides will probably get you where you need to be, particularly if you're just using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Ok. With the `has_many` etc do I use the column name or the class name? i.e. with or without the 's'?

Comment: Read the docs.  SO is not meant to be a replacement for documentation.